# Why react native fetch always return 200 even if login failed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, postman, fetch-api

I use these code to post data to login

```
postJson(url, data, callback){
        var fetchOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body:data
        };
        console.log('begin request');
        fetch(url, fetchOptions)
        .then((response) => {
          responseJson = response.json()
          console.log(responseJson, response.status)
          callback(responseJson)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
  }
```

But quite strange when I use it as

```
postJson(url, formData, (responseJson) => {
           if (responseJson == 200){
              console.log(responseText)
              this.onLoginSuccess();
           }
           else{
              alert('fail');
           }
    })
```

The response code is always 200, but login failed. I have tested the api with postman, it works fine.[image]

actually what console.log(responseJson, response.status) got is

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
} 200
```

Update: this problem is caused by the basic auth in server side. Just add encoding can fix this. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not on server side? Maybe the API you are using has set all status code to 200

Comment: No, the returned data also have some problem. What I got is `"hello, !"`, but what I should get is `"hello, 123!"`

Comment: actually what  `console.log(responseJson, response.status)` got is 
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
} 200

Comment: If the server is always returning 200, the error is on server side

Answer (score 2):

Just like what your console.log’s output is suggesting. `response.json` returns a promise which should be resolved. You should chain another `.then` in order to resolve the promise.

For reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

E.g.:

```
...
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(json => callback(json))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a JSON with an integer, because you are sending it to your callback in here :

```
responseJson = response.json()
console.log(responseJson, response.status)
callback(responseJson) //sending JSON not response.status
```

You need something like this :

`callback(responseJson,response.status)`

and in your calling function :

```
postJson(url, formData, (responseJson, status) => {
           if (status== 200){
              console.log(responseJson)
              this.onLoginSuccess();
           }
           else{
              alert('fail');
           }
    })
```

Comment: I have tried this. but still didn't work. And as you can see I print status in `postJson ` function  `console.log(responseJson, response.status)`, it returns 200.